# How can I programmatically click a Button in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

For a `android.widget.Button` I can use `performClick()` to simulate a click programmatically. But I don't know how to do it in Jetpack Compose. I've looked into the `compose.material` documentation but I at least coudn't find anything about this.

Comment: I think it's not possible right now. What's your use case? Couldn't you just call the same function you call in the button's `onClick` instead of simulating a click?

Comment: @gpunto I want to make a demo for an app and I just can't record myself pressing buttons since it needs to be done several times and be pretty precise regarding the timing. I could just call the `onClick` methods but then I would not have the ripple effect, nor the sound.

Comment: It's not as straightforward as `performClick`, but maybe you could look into UI testing for Compose: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing

Comment: Have you found a work around? I am in the same situation...

Comment: @F.Mysir I needed this some long time ago. But I remember that I used something to perform a touch event on (x,y) coordinate of the screen. Not ideal, I know. This was only for demo purposes and I had obviously only one screen size to consider.

Comment: @daniyelp ok I have founded the solution :)

Answer (score 7):

With this solution you will get the ripple effect programmatically like you have pressed the button:

**1) Create interactionSource:**

```
val interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
```

**2) Create coroutine scope:**

```
val coroutine = rememberCoroutineScope()
```

**3) In your button set interaction source:**

```
Button(
    onClick = {
        vm.myFunction()
    },
    //important
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    .
    .
    .
)
```

**4) Finally call it like so from anywhere:**

```
coroutine.launch {
    val press = PressInteraction.Press(Offset.Zero)
    interactionSource.emit(press)
    vm.myFunction()
    delay(300)
    interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))
}
```

Comment: Nice! But the button's `onClick` is not invoked. Hmm

Comment: @daniyelp In our case it is better to use a viewModel and call the same function the time you launch the coroutine, I have updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's better. Maybe just  good enough. The perfect scenario would be for that `onClick` method to be called when the button appears as clicked. There is no scenario in which I don't want that `onClick` to be called when the button appears as clicked.

Answer (score 5):

In compose you're creating a button with action. You can pass action function and call same function programmatically.

```
// you need to remember your callback to prevent extra recompositions.
// pass all variables that may change between recompositions
// as keys instead of `Unit`
val onClickAction = remember(Unit) { 
    {
        
        // do some action
    }
}

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    // perform action in 1 sec after view appear
    delay(1000)
    onClickAction()
}
Button(
    onClick = onClickAction
) {
    Text(text = "Button")
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just like calling `onClick` but with extra steps?

Comment: @daniyelp I'm not sure what do you mean. `LaunchedEffect` is needed here because you can't call side effects directly from the view builder. Also it gives you a coroutine scope, so you can call `delay` and other suspend functions easily. Check out more in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).  And `remember` is needed to prevent extra recompositions as I've mentioned in the comment

Comment: Sorry, I got into something yesterday. I think we are talking about different things.  With `performClick` I can call a `Button` just like I would have pressed it with my finger. I could have no idea what that button does.  I have a `Compose Button` from a library that I have made and I don't have access to its `OnClickListener`.  I just need to press it, but not with my finger, just using the code. `performClick` also triggers the ripple effect.

Comment: @daniyelp so are you going to test it? Can you pass a modifier to this view?

Comment: I need to make a demo video and I have to press several buttons at fixed time intervals. I can pass modifiers to the views, but I don't know how it could help.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution for that.

1. Create a state variable

   ```
     val verifyNumberOnClick = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
   ```
2. Create a private function that can be used as an action for onClick.

   ```
    private fun makeSum(a: Int, b: Int){
        Log.e("Atiar", "Sum of a & b: ${a+b}")
    }
   ```
3. Create `if-else` to run that function.

   ```
    if (verifyNumberOnClick.value){
        makeSum(5,6)
        verifyNumberOnClick.value = false
    }
   ```
4. You are done. now it's your time to change the value of `verifyNumberOnClick` to `true`.

from anywhere, you will make it true your function will be called. means you can perform onclick tasks from anywhere.

as sample you can change the value of `verifyNumberOnClick` from button on click.

```
Button(
    onClick = {verifyNumberOnClick.value = false}
) {
    Text(text = "Button")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd write an instrumentation test with `ComposeTestRule` for this. `performClick()` generally works as expected for me on a `SemanticNodeInteraction` object.

I did run into a problem where it only worked when the element was currently visible though, so I needed to call `performScrollTo()` first:

```
composeTestRule.onNode(...).run {
    performScrollTo()
    performClick()
}
```